# OutputTo fails in scheduled tasks with "Run even if the user is not logged in"

Tags: ms-access, vba, scheduled-tasks, ms-access-2013

I am trying to figure out why access throws an error when you try to open a report with a filter, then use DoCmd.OutputTo to a pdf file and run it as a scheduled task with the "Run even if the user is not logged in" option. When we run the application regularly, it performs as expected, outputting a list of pdf files properly. The task fails saying it cant output the data to a pdf using OutputTo.

We were able to get this to work when we turn off the "Run even if the user is not logged in" option.

the exact code is as follows

```
Public Function PrintTheThings(argDMRNumber As Integer)
    DoCmd.OpenReport "DMRAutoEmailer_RPT", acViewReport, , "DMRNUMBER = " & argDMRNumber
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "DMRAutoEmailer_RPT", "PDF Format (*.pdf)", "C:\Apps\DMRs\" & argDMRNumber & ".pdf"
    DoCmd.Close acReport, "DMRAutoEmailer_RPT", acSaveNo
End Function
```

where this code executes in a loop.

EDIT: For further clarity, I copied my comment. We created a Windows 10 VM for the express purpose of running automated tasks, this task exports pdfs and emails them out. the user is a domain account that we remoted in with. it was added to the local admin group and the batch execution users group. the destination folder inherits permissions from the c:\apps folder, which the user account has ownership of, and explicitly defined full permissions for. We were manually triggering the task to ensure it worked, but it was set to fire off once a week.

Comment: Did you give Task Scheduler a valid User ID & Password that it can login with?  Does the user have permissions on the destination folder? When is the trigger set to fire?

Comment: @ashleedawg We created a VM for the express purpose of running automated tasks, this task exports pdfs and emails them out. the user is a domain account that we remoted in with. it was added to the local admin group and the batch execution users group. the destination folder inherits permissions from the c:\apps folder, which the user account has ownership of, and explicitly defined permissions for. We were manually triggering the task to ensure it worked.

Comment: Couple questions: Shouldn't you be using `acFormatPDF` instead of `"PDF Format (*.pdf)"`? And is it possible PDF Add-In isn't installed for all users?

Comment: @dbmitch it works when i just run the application normally. it ONLY fails when we run it in task scheduler when the "Run even when user is logged off" option is selected. when we disabled that option, it worked properly.

Comment: A lot of things have to be defined if you're trying to run a task without a user login. It may be temp folder that Access is using or some Add-In that needs to be in the All Users profile. Is your VM a 64 bit system?

Comment: One solution for your problem that worked for someone else was to create folder `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop` AND if 64 bit create this folder too `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop`

Comment: we have no add-ins and yes, it is a 64 bit OS with a 32 bit install of access. I have to ask how those folder paths would have anything to do with outputting a pdf file to the c:\apps\DMRs folder?